# Independence in terms of sigma fields

Tags: self-study, correlation, random-variable, independence, sigma-algebra

I was solving a homework problem that asked for an example of uncorrelated but dependent random variables.
I'm using the example $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$, and $Y=X^2$.

It's straightforward to show that Cov($X,Y)= 0$ but i'm not sure how to rigorously show that they are not independent.

Specifically I want to show that $P(X \in A, Y \in B) \neq P(X\in A) P(Y\in B)$ for $A, B \in \mathcal{B}[-1,1]$. Is this the way to go? How do we do that?

(I want to write this in terms of integrals, but don't know how. What is the measure on $\mathbb{R}$ induced by $Y$?)

Comment: Find specific $A$ and $B$ that violate the independence condition.  You *don't* have to show the condition is always violated--in fact, there are many cases where it is not.  Let $A=B=[0,1],$ for instance.

Comment: @whuber right, so if I let $A = B = [0,1]$ then $P(X\in A, Y\in B) = \frac12 $ but $P(X\in A) = P(Y\in B) = \frac12$

Comment: @whuber I would still like to know how to write this more formally though - how would $P(X\in A, Y\in B)$ be written in integral form? We don't know the joint distribution of $X,Y$.

Comment: In general, it would not be written in terms of integrals.  It suffices to demonstrate you have computed the probabilities correctly.  In your first comment your calculations are all incorrect, BTW: all three probabilities are $1,$ according to the very axioms of probability.

Comment: @whuber oh yes, I meant for the original space to be $[-1,1]$ (easier to show uncorrelated that way). Thanks!